# What do the different shades of green mean in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Other players' names are different colours, yellow/orange for your guildmates, blue for players in your party and so on...

This picture is pretty hectic but you can clearly see at least three different shades of green.

Really bright green, green and a pale green.

What do they mean?

If you right click on the image and *Open image in new tab* you can see it much clearer.

[image]

Comment: For those who don't know, you can toggle the option "Show All Player Names" under _General Options_ -> _User Interface_. Personally, I find seeing a sea of player names more distracting and less... immersive. You can still hold down Alt to see Player/NPC names.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter finally got around to doing this... it's brilliant!! Great tip man!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Now you can actually see what you're fighting ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very bright green names such as "Illusionary Warden", are player 'pets'. Illusionary Warden is a mesmer's phantasm, while some of the other names may be ranger pets, and some of the names in that color appear to be player names but are actually mesmer clones.

The 'middle' green names are player characters.

And the pale green words such as "Champion of the Gods" or "The Sunbringer" are just the titles that the character whose names they are under have obtained and are displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Dark green is title
Bright green is names of computer controlled characters (summons, pets, etc.)
Green-blue'ish one is player names.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't played in couple of weeks, so my memory might be deceiving, but I think that's about right.